# Install Theano and Keras on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, numpy, scipy, theano, keras

I have a question concerning installing keras library on google-app-engine. Through the shell, I have no problem in installing the required libraries, but when I deploy or preview the app, seems that the libraries are not there and it response with error for importing the library. I tried to follow the instructions of google to install third party libraries but I was not successful.

Thanks

The appengine_config, note that numpy is installed in lib folder:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# insert `lib` as a site directory so our `main` module can load
# third-party libraries, and override built-ins with newer
# versions.
vendor.add('lib/numpy/')
```

The error is:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: [As per docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) unless these libraries depend on C extensions - you should be able to simply deploy them with your app. What does the error say exactly? What changes did you make in `appengine_config.py`? Do they correctly reflect the folder structure of your app?

Comment: Thanks @MihailRussu , I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Your `vendor.add()` is referring to the wrong folder, try changing that to:

```
vendor.add('lib')
```

This would assume you ran say:

```
pip install -t lib numpy
```

The imports would be from the base of the `lib/` folder